# Angular2 unit testing on Service fail TypeError: service.getValue is not a function

Tags: angular, unit-testing

> TypeError: service.getValue is not a function

```
let data: string;

@Injectable()
export class MyService {
constructor() {
    myOtherObservableReturning.subscribe((data: mydata) => {
           data.items.forEach((item: Object)  => {
               .....
           }
        ...
        ...
    });
}
   public getValue() { return 'HelloWorld'; }
}
```

unit test:

```
beforeEach(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
        providers: [
            { provide: MyService, useValue: { data: Observable.of(dataStub) } }
        ]
    });
    service = TestBed.get(MyService);
});

it('should be created', () => {
    expect(service).toBeTruthy();
    console.log(JSON.stringify(service)); 
    //LOG: '{"params":{"_isScalar":true,"scheduler":null}}'
});


it('should call getValue', () => {
    //TypeError: service.getValue is not a function
    expect(service.getValue()).toBe('HelloWorld');
});
```

I couldnt figure out why unit test cant find the function `getValue()`, I have already imported and checked its there in the service file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The mistake is in the configureTestingModule.
you don't need to pass an object to Providers, you just have to specify the type. this works:

```
  TestBed.configureTestingModule({
        providers: [
            MyService
        ]
    });
```

However, if you want to specify an alias for the service, or provide other stuff like static urls and such you can specify the metadata object. in your case you miss the class name. The testbed does not know to which class it should resolve the provided MyService Type. This works as well:

```
TestBed.configureTestingModule({
        providers: [
            {provide: MyService, useClass: MyService}
        ]
    });
```

Comment: Hi @lama, I forgot to update the question with a `useValue` that returns a `Observable.of(dataStub)`. My service constructor requires the need of `dataStub`.

Comment: useValue just provides a value as it is. see the chapter on injection token from the docs: https://angular.io/guide/dependency-injection#non-class-dependencies. if you want to inject the data into the constructor, I would do so via the inection token.

Comment: if you have a dependency of your service you can inject that as follows. but I think that only works if your dependency has no dependencies ;)
providers: [
          MyService,
          { provide: MyServiceDependency, useClass: MyServiceDependencyStub }
        ]